# Cannot find css line for element editing

Tags: php, html, css

I cannot find the css line code for the a specific element width.

The elements are on [link deleted]

I need to find the width from the elements in the Recent Estates section and make them fit the width from the image such as the elements from the Featured Estates section

Explicative image :

[image]

Comment: It is inline: `<img class="property-header-image" src="https://www.doctor24.ro/i/uploads/thumbs/4944285729_bfb91833eb.jpg" alt="" style="width:256px">` Question solved?

Comment: No , i need to edit the Css file its not a html to make it hand by hand .

Comment: I figured the width but i make to div containing all the elements on center

Answer (score 1):

You should change the image tag in your html code to the following:

```
<img class="property-header-image" src="https://www.doctor24.ro/i/uploads/thumbs/4944285729_bfb91833eb.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
```

the `width:100%` allows the image to expand to the full width.

Alternatively you can set it via css, but then you have to put `!important` behind the property for it to override the inline css in your html. This is the css code:

```
div.property-header img{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

You also might need to change the image ratio for it to look better.